# Get a range of columns of Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Now I have 300+ columns in my RDD, but I found there is a need to dynamically select a range of columns and put them into LabledPoints data type. As a newbie to Spark, I am wondering if there is any index way to select a range of columns in RDD. Something like `temp_data = data[, 101:211]` in R. Is there something like `val temp_data = data.filter(_.column_index in range(101:211)...`?

Any thought is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be an RDD, or can it be a DataFrame?

Comment: With my limited knowledge, dataframe should be good. Do you have solution if it is in dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a DataFrame, then something like this should work:

```
val df = rdd.toDF
df.select(df.columns.slice(101,211) : _*)
```

Comment: Hi Justin, that didnt worked for me val df = sqlcontext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
      .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .load("C:\\Users\\kalit_000\\Desktop\\typesafe\\spark_safari_mllib\\bulk_data\\churn\\small_combined.tsv")

    df.printSchema()

   df.select(df.columns.slice(0,190): _*)

Comment: @sriharikalicharanTummala what happened?

Comment: I also encounter a bug when I try. Here is the message:
scala> val df2 = df.select(df.columns.slice(0,2) : _*)
<console>:21: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String)
       val df2 = df.select(df.columns.slice(0,2) : _*)
Any idea? I'm running Spark 1.5 as a standalone app

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an RDD of `Array` or any other scala collection (e.g., `List`). You can do something like this:

```
val data: RDD[Array[Int]] = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6)))
val sliced: RDD[Array[Int]] = data.map(_.slice(0,2))

sliced.collect()
> Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(4, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of old thread, but I recently had to do something similar and search around. I needed to select all but the last column where I had 200+ columns.

Spark 1.4.1
 Scala 2.10.4

```
val df = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM foobar")
val cols = df.columns.slice(0, df.columns.length - 1)
val new_df = df.select(cols.head, cols.tail:_*)
```